# Where does Blender 2.8 store theme files on Mac OS?

Tags: interface, theme

Blender 2.8 seems not to store custom theme files in `scripts/presets/interface_theme` anymore. Only the default-themes that ship with Blender by default show up there. I searched my system for the name of my theme but that does not yield any results. So: where does Blender 2.8 store theme files on Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this utility file to get the theme file

```
blender-build/blender/source/tools/utils/blender_theme_as_c.py
```

> Generates 'userdef_default_theme.c' from a 'userpref.blend' file.
>
> Pass your user preferenes blend file to this script to update the C source file.
>
> eg:
>
> ```
> ./source/tools/utils/blender_theme_as_c.py ~/.config/blender/2.80/config/userpref.blend
> ```